# mysql return results based on column results

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to parse a result

Table structure

```
Column 1  | Column 2
A         | if_AT_N 
B         | if_ET_n       
C         | if_AT_n
```

what i'm trying to do is replace column 2 results with "yes" if "_AT is present and "no" if _ET is present

the the goal of the result set would look like

```
A | No
B | Yes
c | NO
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your statement does not match with your desired output. You can interchange the values of `YES` and `NO` that fits your needs.

```
SELECT  Column1,
        IF(Column2 LIKE '%\_AT\_%', 'NO', 'YES') Result
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f389/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║ COLUMN1 ║ RESULT ║
╠═════════╬════════╣
║ A       ║ NO     ║
║ B       ║ YES    ║
║ C       ║ NO     ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

The query above does only the projection. It means that there is no modification in the table. If you want to modify the values of the table, you need to use `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET   Column2 = IF(Column2 LIKE '%\_AT\_%', 'NO', 'YES')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fac9d/1)